# Session is not working in redirect in symfony 1.2

Tags: php, session, symfony-1.2

**Problem**: I set a variable in session before redirection, and it is not working after redirection (in success PHP file)

- I have used symfony setflash/getflash ,session but none method works.

**Code**:
 controller:

```
function abc()
{
    $bold_message="<b>".$gnotes_message->getGnoNote()."</b><br>";
    echo $_SESSION["msge"] =$bold_message;
    $this->getUser()->setFlash('message', $bold_message,true);
    $this->getUser()->setAttribute('msg',$bold_message);
    var_dump($_SESSION["msg"]);die;//output : some message

    return $this->redirect('@homepage');
}
```

signinsucces view file

```
<?php  var_dump($_SESSION['msge']); die("halt");//output: NULL

 if ($sf_user->hasFlash('message')): ?>
   <div class="flash_error"><p><?php echo $sf_user->getFlash('message') ?>       </p></div>
```

```
   <?php echo $sf_user->getFlash('error') ?>           
     </div>
```

- I Have tried simple core concept of setting session in php i.e. `$_session`
- but after redirect session and setflash not working
- I have checked this thread: [Symfony: pass parameter between actions (with a redirect)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229494/symfony-pass-parameter-between-actions-with-a-redirect)

**What I need** is to get access session in success.php file:

```
$this->getUser()->getAttribute('msg');
```